# Javascript Internet Explorer Issue - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've looked through many posts to no avail. I have the following in a simple form where one of the products changes based on the number of checkboxes checked. It works in every browser except IE. What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
"use strict";
var count = 0, x=0, checkboxes=document.signup.getElementsByClassName("styled");
for(;x<checkboxes.length; x++){
    if(checkboxes[x].checked){
        count++;
    }
}
if(count<3) {
   document.getElementById("variable").value = "1";
}
else if (count == 3){

    document.getElementById("variable").value = "74";
}
else if (count == 4){

    document.getElementById("variable").value = "75";
}
else if (count == 5){

    document.getElementById("variable").value = "76";
}

}
</script>
<form name="signup" id="signup" method="post" action="/subscribers/signup.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="variable" name="product_id[]" value="" class="styled"></input>product 1 - variable</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="same" name="product_id[]" value="3" class="styled"></input>product 2
<input type="checkbox" id="same2" name="product_id[]" value="2" class="styled"></input>product 3
<input type="checkbox" id="same3" name="product_id[]" value="4" class="styled"></input><div class="check-title">product 4
<input type="checkbox" id="same4" name="product_id[]" value="44" class="styled"></input><div class="check-title">product 5          
<a href="#" id="submit" onClick="check()">Continue</a></td></tr>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Internet Explorer ;-) Just kidding.

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" – not using the IE developer tools to check for Javascript error messages, or to set breakpoints in the script. A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to let people quickly test your code would be great too. Also, explain what you mention by "works" and "doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle link. I'll do that next time. I'm still rather new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of IE prior to IE9 do not support `getElementsByClassName()`.  You will need to use some sort of substitute.

Instead of this piece of your code:

```
checkboxes = document.signup.getElementsByClassName("styled");
```

I would suggest using this:

```
checkboxes = document.getElementById("signup").getElementsByTagName("input")
```

`getElementsByTagName()` is widely support in all versions of IE.  This will obviously get all `input` tags, but only the checkboxes will have `checked` set so you should be OK.

If you need to filter by class, then you could do the whole thing this way:

```
function check() {
    "use strict";

    // initialize checkbox count to 0
    var count = 0, item;

    // get all input tags in the form
    var inputs = document.getElementById("signup").getElementsByTagName("input");

    // loop through all input tags in the form
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        // get this one into the local variable item
        item = inputs[i];
        // if this input tag has the right classname and is checked, increment the count
        if ((item.className.indexOf("styled") != -1) && item.checked) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    // get object for result
    var obj = document.getElementById("variable");
    // check count and set result based on the count
    if(count < 3) {
        obj.value = "1";
    } else if (count == 3) {
        obj.value = "74";
    } else if (count == 4) {
        obj.value = "75";
    } else if (count == 5) {
        obj.value = "76";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where/when have you returned (filter) the array ? Only selected checked checkboxes should be returned, isn't it ?

Comment: @Heera - I think you haven't seen the latest edits to my answer.  Let me know if you still have questions after seeing that.

Comment: Holy smoly y'all are fast. Good to know about getElementsByClassName(). Thanks.

Comment: First of all you've selected all inputs in the inputs array and then you've  done loop through the array and fetched the first item in the item variable without checking the input whether it's selected or not but later you've checked is it checked or not and then you've made the loop continue. How could it possible to get all the selected check boxes using your code ?

Comment: @Heera - The second block of code I have counts the `input` tags in the `signup` form with a class of `styled` and the checked attribute set and puts the result in the `count` variable.  That will get you the number of checkboxes that are checked in your form.  I thought that's what you were trying to do.  Did you try it?  Or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: I'm didn't try it, just looking at your code and trying to figure out how it'll work.

Comment: You didn't put the result in the count instead you've increased count variable that will contain only an integer value but where is the array that contains all checked inputs ?

Comment: @Heera - The array of input tags is in the `inputs` variable.  The `for` loop goes through each input tag, assigns it to the local variable `item` and then checks to see if that `item` has the right `className` and if it is `checked`.  If it has the right `className` and is `checked`, it increments the `count` variable.  That's what your original code was trying to do so that's what this code does.   There is no array that contains all the checked inputs because you didn't ask for that in your question or in your sample code.  This code counts the number of checked checkboxes.

Comment: Oh man! I didn't asked the question just trying to find out how this code is capable of fetching all the checked inputs and I've got it now that you didn't returned any array.

Comment: @discerninc - I've made one more edit to my answer to put the entire code block in.  Also, you have all sorts of errors in your HTML (unclosed `DIV` tags, invalid `</input>` tags, unmatched `</td></tr>` tags, etc...).

Comment: @Heera - sorry I thought you were the OP.  I've added comments to the code to explain it.

Answer (score -1):

IE doesnt have method getElementsByClassName... you can try to define it:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) { 
   document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) { 
      var retnode = []; 
      var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b'); 
      var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) { 
         var classes = elem[i].className; 
         if (myclass.test(classes)) { 
            retnode.push(elem[i]); 
         } 
      } 
      return retnode; 
   } 
};
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP because they aren't calling `getElementsByClassName()` on the document object, but on another object in the DOM.